# Supporting multiple schemes in one binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have developed a custom binding which works over http and therefore returns `http` as it's scheme. My current code to return this scheme is as follow:

My derivation of `Binding` uses

```
public override string Scheme {
    get { return this.transportElement.Scheme; }
}
```

where transportElement is an instance of my custom `TransportBindingElement`, where the scheme is returned directly by

```
public override string Scheme {
    get { return "http"; }
}
```

. Now, I want to add support for `https`. Depending on the scheme, my channels should open secure connections if requested by the users of my binding.

Is it possible to expose multiple schemes for one binding?

- If yes, how can I do this (since `Scheme` returns only a `string`?)
- If no, what approach should I take to fulfil my wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be to enable support for a `security mode` flag, and to change the code to dynamically return a scheme which depends on this flag.